# Excluding a link using Jquery $(select)

Tags: jquery, function, prettyphoto

I am using [ContentFlow](http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/) for an image gallery and when the image centers in the flow it becomes `.active`. I have the following function to enable a PrettyPhoto lightbox when a thumbnail image becomes `.active` but I need to exclude links to additional image galleries when the the link thumbnail ( which is a folder) becomes active.

This is my current code for PrettyPhoto:

```
currentLink         : '.item.active',
currentFolder       : '.folder',
currentImg          : '.item.active .content'



function initCBox(){
    var img1 = $(select.currentLink).attr('href');
    var label = $(select.currentImg).attr('alt');
    var desc = $.map( $('.item.active .caption')[0].childNodes, function(val,i) {
        if (val.nodeType === 3) {
            return val.data;
        }
    }).join('');
    $.prettyPhoto.open(img1,label,desc);
}
```

I am trying to use not to exclude the folders as such:

```
function initCBox(){
    var img1 = $(select.currentLink).not('currentFolder').attr('href');
    var label = $(select.currentImg).attr('alt');
    var desc = $.map( $('.item.active .caption')[0].childNodes, function(val,i) {
    if (val.nodeType === 3) {
            return val.data;
        }
    }).join('');
    $.prettyPhoto.open(img1,label,desc);
}
```

It's not working so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting any JavaScript errors? How did you declare the variables?

Comment: Sorry, I was vague on that! The variables are declared within the Contentflow function as above: 
`currentLink         : '.item.active',
currentFolder       : '.folder',
currentImg          : '.item.active .content' `and the jQuery function is within that.

Comment: My code does not throw errors in Firebug